# Handling a SIGSEGV in kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need some help about extend the signal sending functionality in kernel space in the presence of a `SIGSEGV`.
I have been working on OPTEE-OS (see the image at the bottom) and when a program, which is running on the RICH OS (in my case linux), crashes for some reason i need to forward the crash detected to the OPTEE Trustzone. I do not need to forward crash details or core dump file to the TrustZone but only that the process with pid XXXXXX crashed.

I know SIGSEGV is caught by the MMU causing an interrupt and that interrupt is handled by the kernel, which sends a SIGSEGV signal to the process. I want to extend the kernel module which sends the SIGSEGV signal in order to forward information to the TrustZone. But i do not know which kernel module in linux i could edit to do that.

For instance by starting with a simple .c code

```
void foo(int *p) {
*p = 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int *p = NULL;
foo(p);
}
```

which returns a `SIGSEGV` my question is:

- Which kernel module should i edit in order to send the information to the Trustzone ? I think it is not a complex task because i just have to import the TruztZone library in the kernel module so as to do that .

[OP-TEE ARCHITECTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRyvK.png)

Comment: In general the CPU or MMU causes a fault when the program executes an invalid instruction or accesses an illegal memory address. This traps into the kernel, the trap handler turns this into a process signal like SIGSEG, SIGILL.

Comment: Here is a similar question marked as SOLVED on another forum: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-detect-a-crashed-application-841731/

Comment: @Barmar Thank for your reply. Do you know the kernel module which i should edit ? is there any docs ?

Comment: No, I just know the general process used in most operating systems, not the specific code for Linux.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC Thank you i  had already seen that answer but maybe it does not help me

Comment: I suggest you search the sources for `SIGSEGV`, so see where that signal is triggered.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I am searching for an answer but i am reading online it is not a good practice to use `sys_rt_sigaction`  to do that because it is meant to be called from user space

Comment: `which is running on the RICH OS (in my case linux), crashes for some reason i need to forward the crash detected to the OPTEE Trustzone` you asked XY question. Install a coredump handler that we do what you want. It's unrelated to how kernel handles SIGSEGV.

Comment: @KamilCuk It is not unrelated because i do not know which kernel module do that. Why should i install a coredump handler ? i need to do that in kernel space

Comment: @KamilCuk If you could tell me which kernel module sends `SIGSEGV` signal i can make it do what I need

Comment: Still, I would install coredump handler to communicate with kernel Trustzone driver via user-space || It's not a module, it's internal to kernel, _very_ specific to specific architecture. As above, search for SIGSEGV in kernel sources, and you'll find many result in specific architecture tree. Which arch https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch is your platform? Seg fault occurs when trying to access invalid memory - so you are basically searching for page fault handler. Basically https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1220 is for x86

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you !  I thought to communicate with kernel Truszone by using optee_linuxdriver rather than a coredump handler. Do you think i can use that page fault handler for x86 by adding the part of forwarding the infromation to the Trustzone ?

Comment: `optee_linuxdriver` No idea what that is, oin github page has a big fat DEPRECATED text https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_linuxdriver . This driver https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tee/optee/core.c#L217 seems to expose driver https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/staging/tee.html , which is for  communication with user space. I still fail to understand _why_ you do not want to write a userspace coredump handler, seems _way_ easier then modifying kernel.

Comment: `Do you think i can...` no idea, that's for a developer that will try to implement that to find out. Are you sure you are capable of doing kernel modifications? For starters, are you sure you are on x86? Overall, is there a trustzone for x86 architecture? Kernel programming is _really hard_, I do not understand why would you _want_ it. The question from previous comment remains: `Which arch from elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch is your target platform?`

Comment: @KamilCuk I am working on arm 32 bit. I am looking at this one https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mm/fault.c#L132